# Allowing users to login via FB and login by making an account on your website

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, facebook, django-templates

I want to give people the opportunity of logging into my site using FB or by making an account on my site. At the moment I have separate pages for the two options.

**urls.py**

```
 path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),

path('abc/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='blog/index.html'), name="facebook")
```

I changed the name from facebook to abc to make sure that the name had nothing to do with the issue. When I click on the Login With Facebook button, every thing works fine.

[image]

When I click Login on this screen, everything works fine. When I click Login with FB, nothing happens.

[image]

The account with username RossSymondsFacebook does not have a username because this account was generated by me logging into my Facebook account.

[image]

**index.html**

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}

        <head>
            <title>Facebook Registration</title>
        </head>

<button class="btn"><a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Login With Facebook</a></button>
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log In</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">

            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login</button>



        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Need An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up Now</a>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>



<article class="media content-section">
<button class="btn"><a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Login With Facebook</a></button>

</article>


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I think its better if you use Facebook API

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean that example , I have a Facebook accout with an email afosjw@yahoo.com and ita password is jsjsjsjaj . If I entered it there, my credentials will be used in facebook as a login?

Comment: Becauae if yoy do not used Facebook API, it will served as an phishing because you can see what people entered .Here is the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: I made an API on Facebook For Developers. To the best of my knowledge my site is already programmed to work with that API.

Comment: Do you mean that example , I have a Facebook accout with an email afosjw@yahoo.com and ita password is jsjsjsjaj . If I entered it there, my credentials will be used in facebook as a login? - Yes that is what I mean

Comment: Did you used this ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by changing my code to the below.

**login.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log In</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">

                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login</button>



            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Need An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up Now</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>

{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
<article class="media content-section">

<button class="btn btn-outline-info"><a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="js_sdk" %}">Login With Facebook</a></button>


</article>
 {% endblock content %}
```